# IGNORE "column was specified multiple times for" CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

With the following CTE:

```
WITH cteRoute AS (
    SELECT *
      FROM CRROUTE cr 
      JOIN crewleg cl on (cr.CDATE = cl.CDATE AND cr.CROUTE = cl.croute)
      left JOIN legmain lm on (lm.DAY = cl.DAY AND lm.DEP = cl.DEP and lm.CARRIER = cl.CARRIER and lm.FLT = cl.FLT and lm.LEGCD = cl.LEGCD )
      left JOIN legtimes lt on (lt.DAY = lm.DAY AND lt.DEP = lm.DEP and lt.CARRIER = lm.CARRIER and lt.FLT = lm.FLT and lt.LEGCD = lm.LEGCD )
      where cr.cdate = 14000
      and cr.croute = 138266498116
)
```

I get an error saying that CARRIER has been selected multiple times in the CTE.

And yes, that is correct.  Because of the `SELECT *` it has indeed been selected multiple times.

My question is **not** how to fix that.  I know how to fix that by specifically enumerating the specific columns in the query instead of selecting them all via `SELECT *.`

The problem is that the database I am working with is from a third party vendor (in Greece), over which I have no control, and they are VERY, uhm, "sloppy" in their database design and normalization.

**This query is going to return a couple HUNDRED columns.**  I really do not want to have to specifically enumerate them all.

The SQL Server query engine is quite capable of pulling multiple columns of the same name:

```
SELECT 'this' as LABEL, 'that' as LABEL
```

Will work just fine, returning two columns BOTH named "LABEL".

My question is, **is there a way to tell the Query Engine to ignore the duplicate column names in a common table expression?**

It's able to do so in a normal query (as shown above), but it seems unable to do it in a CTE.

The columns in question are columns used in the JOIN linkage, and they will always be equal.

### Update

This question is *similar* to other questions, but has a *unique nuance* that makes it NOT a duplicate. If this one actually **IS** a duplicate, then by all means, do flag it as such, and I will be quite happy - especially if it has an answer.

Comment: If what I am asking is simply not possible, I would appreciate suggestions on what I can do to minimize "finger strain" if I am forced to explicitly name every one of the columns in the query.

Comment: To begin with, we know nothing about the engine you are using. Standard SQL doesn't allow for duplicate column names.

Comment: @drum - I specifically mentioned that my server is SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to reduce what has to be manually typed out.

Run the following code

```
  SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN t.name = 'crewleg' THEN 'cl.' + c.name + ','
      WHEN t.name = 'legmain' THEN 'lm.' + c.name + ','
      WHEN t.name = 'legtimes' THEN 'lt.' + c.name + ','
    END
  FROM sys.tables t
  join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
  WHERE t.name in ('crewleg', 'legmain', 'legtimes')
```

This will return every column prefaced by the `alias` and `.` along with a comma following the column name. Copy this to notepad. At this point you can just go do a find for the columns that will cause the issues and give them an alias so they won't be duplicates. Also you can use notepad ++ to find and replace all the carriage returns so the select won't be so long vertically. Don't forget to remove very last comma as it will be extra. Then just copy and paste it back into your select.